# Relink renamed mesh

Tags: mesh, linked-data

I've linked object with mesh from external "asset" blend file. Then I've decided to rename mesh there as I was cleaning up names. Is it possible to quickly relink mesh in main file? It's no problem to relink blend file by chaging path in "blender file" outliner section, but haven't found way to relink mesh.

Best regs.

Comment: Match the names of the models in both blends?.

Comment: With the [Project Glue](https://blendermarket.com/products/project-glue) addon, you can perform a rename operation where the users of the data-block are automatically updated to the new name.